# PHP For each loop on nested associated array

Tags: php, json

I've made a call with cURL on an api and using json_decode as seen below.

```
$data = json_decode($response,true);
print_r ($data);
```

I get the following when printing it to the browser which is what I would expect.

```
array (
  'Appointments' => 
    array (
     0 => 
     array (
     'FullName' => 'Joe Bloggs',
     'Age' => '19',
     'DateTimeOfBirth' => '1999-10-28T10:15:00',
     ),
     1 => 
     array (
     'FullName' => 'John Smith',
     'Age' => '19',
     'DateTimeOfBirth' => '1999-10-28T10:15:00',
     ),
     ),
     'FutureAppointments' => 
     array (
     ),
     )
```

I want to filter on this but can't figure out how to target the nested array. I'm trying the following but obviously only getting the first level:

```
foreach($data as $key => $name){
    echo $key . ' - ' . $name;
}
```

My output in the browser is:

Appointments - **Array**
FutureAppointments - **Array**

How would I do a 'foreach' to target '**FullName**' which seems to be two levels down so my output would be:

Joe Bloggs, John Smith

Comment: Does `foreach ($data['Appointments'] as $person) {` work? Then there's `$person['FullName']` etc inside the loop block.

Comment: @ggorlen 100% that's worked! Thanks!

Comment: All right, glad it worked out. I'm going to vote to close as "no longer reproducible/resolved in a way that might not be useful to future visitors" since the question is basically "how to index into an array with a string key".